# Does Fedora 31 ship with Nvidia drivers?

Tags: fedora, nvidia

I was eagerly waiting for the release of Fedora 31, as I'm pretty darn sure that I read earlier that it would ship with Nvidia drivers like Pop!_OS or Ubuntu.

However, now that it's just been released, I can't find any mention of it.

**Does Fedora 31 ship with proprietary Nvidia drivers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

Fedora is a 100% free/libre Operating System and as long their philosophy doesn't change it will never contain any proprietary blobs/microcode/code.

Comment: Red hat, Fedora backer, has a strong free software philosophy